# Not able to host ASP .NET core 3.1 with angular inside IIS default website

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-3.1

I am not able to host ASP.NET core 3.1 with an angular template app inside the IIS default website. The hosting works and angular app lanches if it is hosted as a standalone website in IIS. I have used default InProcess web hosting. But the same hosting fails to load when added inside the default website. Below error shown in the browser console tab:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
polyfills-es2015.7cfdeea462673f342285.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main-es2015.a7b9ab4b981098542774.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles.747581a485d8163d58ca.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

My web.config looks as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\XXXXX.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
      stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Is there anything that is needed extra in case of hosting it inside the default website? This is strange as the same works if hosted independently. I am not sure why it is not able to find angular resources inside the default website. I also tried adding a URL rewrite inside web.config but to my surprise that also did not work.

To mention, .net core 3.1 runtime and the respective hosting bundle is installed on the machine.And app pool targets "no managed code".Nothing is getting logged via stdoutLogFile, so no clue what is happening.

Comment: Is your default website file location pointing to the wwwroot folder? Can you post any screenshots that show where these files are when you are running it under the Default Website vs. Hosting as it's own separate page? The error indicates that the location of the compiled Angular files is not where they expect to be...so we need to find out where it is looking for them.

Comment: In both cases they are picked up from C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestWebApp.The compiled angular files are inside C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestWebApp\ClientApp\dist.

Answer (score 0):

For getting it to run as the default website, instead of having the files in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestWebApp` put them in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`, so `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ClientApp\dist`. This should fix the issue, the default website is looking for the files in wwwroot, not a subfolder.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yes, you are correct. But I wanted my redistributables to be inside a website's directory (in my case inside TestWebApp ).After moving files from C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestWebApp\ClientApp\dist to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestWebApp worked for me.I also need to update base href in index.html to point to the website's root folder.Like this:<base href="/TestWebApp/" />. After this, it works without any issues.